# Product rule for limits of functions

Tags: calculus, limits

When asking wolfram alpha to solve the following limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3^x+\ln|x|}{x^5+x^4}$$ it uses the following step: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3^x+\ln|x|}{x^5+x^4} =\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^5+x^4} \times \lim_{x \to 0}\left(3^x+\ln|x|\right).$$ Can you really do this, since the limit for $\frac{1}{x^4+x^5}\rightarrow \infty$ ?

I have read the the product rule for limits is "if the limit for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exists when $x$ goes to $a$ then $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x)=(\lim_{x \to a}f(x))(\lim_{x \to a}g(x))$ and the other way around"

Answer (score 1):

Because both the limits tend to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$, that separation is allowed and raises no ambiguity. The ambiguity may only happen only if one of the indefinite limits (such as $\infty\times 0$) happens. An example is
$$
{\lim_{x\to 0} x\times {1\over x}
\\
\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\times {1\over x}
\\
\lim_{x\to 0} x\times {1\over x^2}
}
$$